# how to loop results in slider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

i have 3 sliders i want to loop the slider with my results can you help me out.

this sliders are heart of my website, i can add slider or edit slider or delete slider from admin panel but im not getting how can i fetch.

```html
<?php
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM r_slider WHERE status=1 order by id_slider desc")or die(mysql_error());
    ?>

<section class="slider_wrap slider_fullwide slider_engine_revo slider_alias_education_home_slider">

    <div id="rev_slider_1_1_wrapper" class="rev_slider_wrapper fullwidthbanner-container">                    
  <div id="rev_slider_1_1" class="rev_slider fullwidthabanner disp_none height_630 max-height_630">
   <ul>
<?php while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)) { ?>
                            <!-- Slide 1 -->
    <li data-transition="random" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="300" data-saveperformance="off">
     <img src="images/green.jpg" alt="green" data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="normal" data-bgrepeat="repeat">
     <div class="tp-caption customin stl cust-z-index-5 rs-cust-style8" data-x="20" data-y="230" data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:90;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:1;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:20;transformOrigin:50% 100%;" data-speed="1300" data-start="500" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-end="8250" data-endspeed="300">
     <img src="images/post/<?php echo $result['image'] ?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
     </div>
     <div class="tp-caption title sfr stl tp-resizeme cust-z-index-6 rs-cust-style1" data-x="570" data-y="190" data-speed="500" data-start="1350" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-end="8400" data-endspeed="300"><?php echo $result['title']; ?>
     </div>
     <div class="tp-caption slide_text sfr stl tp-resizeme cust-z-index-7 rs-cust-style2" data-x="570" data-y="380" data-speed="500" data-start="1750" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-end="8500" data-endspeed="300">
      <span class="font-w_400"><?php echo $result['description']; ?></span>
     </div>
     <div class="tp-caption slide_button customin stl tp-resizeme cust-z-index-8 rs-cust-style3" data-x="570" data-y="460" data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:90;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:1;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:-20;transformOrigin:50% 0%;" data-speed="500" data-start="2200" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-end="8600" data-endspeed="300">
      <a href="#" class="slide_button_white">Start Learning Now</a>
     </div>
    </li>
    <!-- Slide 2 -->
<li data-transition="random" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="300" data-saveperformance="off">
     <img src="images/blue.jpg" alt="blue" data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="normal" data-bgrepeat="repeat">
     <div class="tp-caption customin stl cust-z-index-5 rs-cust-style8" data-x="40" data-y="200" data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:360;scaleX:0.1;scaleY:0.1;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:0;transformOrigin:50% 50%;" data-speed="1300" data-start="500" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-end="8250" data-endspeed="300">
      <img src="images/slide-2-1.png" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="tp-caption title sfb stb tp-resizeme cust-z-index-6 rs-cust-style1" data-x="570" data-y="200" data-speed="500" data-start="1350" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-end="8400" data-endspeed="300">Education Center
      <br> and distance education
     </div>
     <div class="tp-caption slide_text sfb stb tp-resizeme cust-z-index-7 rs-cust-style2" data-x="570" data-y="355" data-speed="500" data-start="1750" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-end="8500" data-endspeed="300">
      <span class="font-w_400">Online Education leads the world in distance education with high quality online degrees and online courses.</span>
     </div>
     <div class="tp-caption slide_button customin stb tp-resizeme cust-z-index-8 rs-cust-style3" data-x="570" data-y="460" data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:90;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:1;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:20;transformOrigin:50% 100%;" data-speed="500" data-start="2200" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-end="8600" data-endspeed="300">
      <a href="#" class="slide_button_white">Start Learning Now</a>
     </div>
    </li>
    <!-- Slide 3 -->
<li data-transition="random" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="300" data-saveperformance="off">
     <img src="images/yellow.jpg" alt="yellow" data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="normal" data-bgrepeat="repeat">
     <div class="tp-caption roundedimage sfl stl cust-z-index-5 rs-cust-style8" data-x="50" data-y="200" data-speed="1300" data-start="500" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-end="8250" data-endspeed="300">
      <img src="images/slide-3-1.jpg" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="tp-caption title customin stb tp-resizeme cust-z-index-6 rs-cust-style1" data-x="570" data-y="200" data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:90;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:1;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:20;transformOrigin:50% 100%;" data-speed="500" data-start="1350" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-end="8400" data-endspeed="300">Receive personalized
      <br> coaching
     </div>
     <div class="tp-caption slide_text customin stb tp-resizeme cust-z-index-7 rs-cust-style2" data-x="570" data-y="355" data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:90;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:1;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:20;transformOrigin:50% 100%;" data-speed="500" data-start="1750" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-end="8500" data-endspeed="300" >
      <span class="font-w_400">Learning is a collaborative process, and we're here to provide you with guidance every step of the way.</span>
     </div>
     <div class="tp-caption slide_button customin stb tp-resizeme cust-z-index-8 rs-cust-style3" data-x="570" data-y="460" data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:90;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:1;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:20;transformOrigin:50% 100%;" data-speed="500" data-start="2200" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-end="8600" data-endspeed="300">
      <a href="#" class="slide_button_white">Start Learning Now</a>
     </div>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
                        </ul>

   <div class="tp-bannertimer"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
    
</section>
```

Comment: where are you stuck ? do you try to loop the sliders with javascript ? If yes please share your javascript code, if not please clearify your question in what you're trying to achive.

Comment: Is it not possible without javascript code..?

Comment: please explain what you're trying to achive, what should be the result ?